# Qt: No android kits found

Tags: android, qt

The kit was there untill I updated Qt due to certain problem.

In `option > android` I have set everything up, such as the `SDK`, `NDK`, `Ant` and `JDK`.

Below `NDK` it says it has found 6 toolchains.

[image]

In the kits section it only auto-detected one, which is the *desktop*...

Comment: You mean QtCreator, not Qt, right? Which operating system is this, which has QtCreator version update happened, etc?

Comment: Yes. Qtcreator. I updated to 5.2.1 but now I am using 5.3 RC

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/a46cs1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not selected any Qt version. You should select something like Qt 5.3 (Android_ARMV7) for that field.

You can also Goto `Tools > Option > Android` settings page and make sure `Automatically create kits for Android tool chains` is checked, and apply it. If you check this option, it will create the kit with an appropriate name.

Now, goto `Tools > Option > Build and Run` settings page, and click on `Kits` tab and check if Qt Creator created the Android kits.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem - it was because I hadn't installed the QT compilers for Android.

To fix it, you need to go back to the installer (may need to uninstall the current version or install in a new directory) and expand the QT version you're using then check the relevant Android packages to be installed.  Once the install is complete, set the SDK, NDK, JDK, and Ant and it should show the new kits in the build and run page.

Comment: Good point. But with the last Qt Maintenance Tool there is no need to uninstall anything. You only have to expand the Qt version and check the Android packages.